# Block calls/messages in react native application

Tags: java, react-native, block, message, callblocking

how to block calls and messages on phone using react-native application, can't find any dependency or service of react-native.
if anyone have worked kindly help.
is it possible with java service or any alternate way?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: kindly Review, i have updated the details